# Start fragment on opening Push Notification?

Tags: android, android-fragments, parse-platform, push-notification, navigation-drawer

- Right now I am using **parse.com** to send the push notification to the users using my android app.
- I m able to receive the notification and on clicking on app is starting normally. I am using CustomBroadCastReceiver that extends ParsePushBroadCastReceiver.

Here is the code of the Receiver :

```
package com.myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;

public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushDismiss(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushDismiss(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushOpen(context,intent);
    }
}
```

- I am trying to open the WhatsNew Fragment when onPushOpen will be called. But the problem is that I am using Navigationdrawer for my app. whenever I click on the notification app lands on the starting activity which is MainActivity having code as follows:

  ```
  package com.myapp;

  import android.app.Fragment;
  import android.app.FragmentManager;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

  import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
  import com.parse.ParseInstallation;


  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
          implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

  /**
   * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
   */
  private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
  private Toolbar mToolbar;
  private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
      setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

      mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
              getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

      // Set up the drawer.
      mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
      ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
      ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
  }

  @Override
  public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
      // update the main content by replacing fragments
      Fragment fragment;
      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); // For AppCompat use getSupportFragmentManager
      switch (position) {
          default:
          case 0:
              fragment = new Authentication();//search property
              break;
          case 1:
              fragment = new Home();//post property
              break;
          case 2:
              fragment = new PostRequirement();//post requirement
              break;
          case 3:
              fragment = new Properties();//popular locations keep it blank
              break;
          case 4:
              fragment = new Blog();//blog
              break;
          case 5:
              fragment = new Contact();//contact
              break;
          case 6:
              fragment = new NewFragment();
              break;
      }
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
  }


  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
      if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
          mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
      else
          super.onBackPressed();
  }
  }
  ```
- On opening the push notification app lands on the **Authentication Fragment**. What I want to do is to open that **NewFragment** whenever user will open the app through push notification.

Manifest file for the application :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".ParseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.NoConnection"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>


        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.myapp.Receiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.myapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

- I did lot of research for the problem but didn't get satisfied answer. Intent can't be used to call the fragment so was not able to pass the Intent in **OnPushOpen** method
- What should I do so that whenever **user will click on the push notification** app will land on the **NewFragment** instead of **Authentication Fragment.**
- Thank you for taking long time to read the question! But I am really messed up with this thing.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you cannot launch a fragment when you receive a push notification. Instead you can launch a new activity which can display the new notification on a sperate screen/layout.

For that  go to  your ParseApplication.java

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, keys.applicationId, keys.clientKey);
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, NewActivity.java);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveEventually();
    }
```

Basically when ever you get a notification and the user clicks, it loads the `NewActivity.java` which in turn opens the xml file.

Now in `NewActivity.java` go to its `onCreate` in that in `setContentView`

```
setContentView(R.layout.**layout name**);
```

put your xml file.

If you want to retain the push notification which you send, use shared preferences.

Comment: Are you sure that we cant start fragment which is in the mainactivity?

Comment: I tried to do, but could not, anyway just try my method

Comment: Sure,Thank you for your help buddy!

Answer (score 0):

You should add a parameter to bundle from YourBroadCastReceiver indicating to go to new Fragment and from inside the activity go to that Fragment checking the given parameter from given bundle.